# Integrate Google Search Appliance with Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-search-appliance

I wanted to integrate GSA with Rails. But the web proved to be un-helpful. Anybody knows any step-by-step tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the gem `rails-gsa` this will help you a lot in integrating the Google Search Appliance with your rails Application.

Check out the documentation on github https://github.com/rohit9889/rails-gsa

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to call the GSA with the search query. The reference informations for generating the GET-request is here: http://code.google.com/apis/searchappliance/documentation/610/xml_reference.html#SubmittingaSearchRequest

Then you will receive a xml response from the GSA with all needed information inside. The reference for the xml nodes are here (Look better at a xml response from your GSA and get additional informations in my link): http://code.google.com/apis/searchappliance/documentation/610/xml_reference.html#results_xml_tags

Last but not least, you have to parse the informations within the xml and generate your custom frontend.

I hope that will help you. It isn't really complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Define "integrate" closer. The most things are language independent and have nothing to do with Rails/Java/.Net or whatever

Comment: send request(search query) to gsa and get the response(search results, pagination links, dynamic navigation) and then render them on views